Articulate 360 Storyline Apply Slide Master Layout
When I try to apply a layout from slide master, it shows all of the layouts highlighted and none of them can be clicked on.
I have done this 3 times without issue, yet it has suddenly frozen. Oddly, the slide master states that none of the layouts are used by slides, when they are being used.
Storyline Example Image:


Any slide from slide master needs at least one layout before it can be applied to a slide. Go to view -> slide master -> insert layout.
